# Convert dataframe to a rec array (and objects to strings)

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy

I have a pandas dataframe with a mix of datatypes (dtypes) that I wish to convert to a numpy structured array (or record array, basically the same thing in this case).  For purely numeric dataframes, this is easy to do with the `to_records()` method.  I also need the dtypes of pandas columns to be converted to *strings* rather than *objects* so that I can use the numpy method `tofile()` which will output numbers and strings to a binary file, but will not output objects.

**In a nutshell, I need to convert pandas columns with `dtype=object` to numpy structured arrays of string or unicode dtype.**

Here's an example, with code that would be sufficient if all columns had a numerical (float or int) dtype.

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.DataFrame({'f_num': [1.,2.,3.], 'i_num':[1,2,3], 
                 'char': ['a','bb','ccc'], 'mixed':['a','bb',1]})

struct_arr=df.to_records(index=False)

print('struct_arr',struct_arr.dtype,'\n')

# struct_arr (numpy.record, [('f_num', '<f8'), ('i_num', '<i8'), 
#                            ('char', 'O'), ('mixed', 'O')])
```

But because I want to end up with string dtypes, I need to add this additional and somewhat involved code:

```
lst=[]
for col in struct_arr.dtype.names:  # this was the only iterator I 
                                    # could find for the column labels
    dt=struct_arr[col].dtype

    if dt == 'O':   # this is 'O', meaning 'object'

        # it appears an explicit string length is required
        # so I calculate with pandas len & max methods
        dt = 'U' + str( df[col].astype(str).str.len().max() )
       
    lst.append((col,dt))

struct_arr = struct_arr.astype(lst)
        
print('struct_arr',struct_arr.dtype)

# struct_arr (numpy.record, [('f_num', '<f8'), ('i_num', '<i8'), 
#                            ('char', '<U3'), ('mixed', '<U2')])
```

See also:  [How to change the dtype of certain columns of a numpy recarray?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9949427/how-to-change-the-dtype-of-certain-columns-of-a-numpy-recarray)

This seems to work, as the character and mixed dtypes are now `<U3` and `<U2` rather than 'O' or 'object'.  I'm just checking if there is a simpler or more elegant approach.  But since pandas does not have a native string type as numpy does, maybe there is not?

Comment: `dt=df['mixed'].values.astype(str).dtype` works for me.

Comment: I'd be tempted to cannibalize `to_records`, incorporating your dtype conversion.  It's iterating on the columns, and building the array with `np.rec.fromarrays`.

Comment: Have you looked at the code for that function?

Comment: I suppose 'cannibalize' is more commonly applied to machinery, such as wrecked airplanes, than to programming and functions.

Comment: @hpaulj  Thanks, it was a good suggestion and I included in my answer to my own question.  Also a nice use of 'cannibalize', I just didn't catch the meaning at first. ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Combining suggestions from @jpp (list comp for conciseness) & @hpaulj (cannibalize `to_records` for speed), I came up with the following, which is cleaner code and also about 5x faster than my original code (tested by expanding the sample dataframe above to 10,000 rows):

```
names = df.columns
arrays = [ df[col].get_values() for col in names ]

formats = [ array.dtype if array.dtype != 'O' 
            else f'{array.astype(str).dtype}' for array in arrays ] 

rec_array = np.rec.fromarrays( arrays, dtype={'names': names, 'formats': formats} )
```

The above will output unicode rather than strings which is probably better in general but in my case I need to convert to strings because I'm reading the binary file in fortran and strings seem to read in more easily.  Hence, it may be better to replace the "formats" line above with this:

```
formats = [ array.dtype if array.dtype != 'O' 
            else array.astype(str).dtype.str.replace('<U','S') for array in arrays ]
```

E.g. a dtype of `<U4` becomes `S4`.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I am aware, there is no native functionality for this. For example, the maximum length of all values within a series is not stored anywhere.

However, you can implement your logic more efficiently via a list comprehension and f-strings:

```
data_types = [(col, arr[col].dtype if arr[col].dtype != 'O' else \
               f'U{df[col].astype(str).str.len().max()}') for col in arr.dtype.names]
```

Comment: Thanks!  I hate to check mark my own answer but this ended up being half of what I needed (although a very nice half  ;-)